# Forcing activity to run an activity in landscape in android 1.5

Tags: android

I have an application which is in portrait mode. However, I want to run a particular activity in landscape mode. I have tried the following with no success.

```
1. android:screenOrientation="landscape" in AndroidManifest.xml
2. this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); in activity requiring landscape mode
```

as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150287/force-an-android-activity-to-always-use-landscape-mode). Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifest solution supplied in [the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150287/force-an-android-activity-to-always-use-landscape-mode) definitely works. [Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Preview/) using `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. It doesn't work. Actually, what happens in this case is, when I go to activity which requires landscape mode, the activity doesn't begin, I see toggling of landscape mode to portrait for some time and screen goes blank. :(