# Forcing 'portrait' orientation not working - any tips?

Tags: android, xml, view, orientation, portrait

Hey all - I have tried to only display my app in portrait view orientation to no avail.

I have the code:  android:screenOrientation="portrait"  in every button, ImageView, TextView, etc... in my xml files but when I tilt the phone to the side, it still goes into landscape view.

I do call the camera in my app, but I don't think that is the issue - any thoughts?

Comment: AHhh that was super stupid on my part - I never put it in the manifest...thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the layout is the wrong place. you have to place it in the activity like this:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" ...>
```

[Force an Android activity to always use landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150287/force-an-android-activity-to-always-use-landscape-mode)

is google that hard to understand? google "android force portrait" and the first four links shows the answer... (sorry.. just had to let it out :) )

Comment: AHhh that was super stupid on my part - I never put it in the manifest...thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the android:screenOrientation="portrait" in the AndroidManifest.xml.

In **AndroidManifest.xml** you have to do something like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".Your_Activity_Name"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```