# How to check when the phone changues from portrait to landscape? (with portrait mode forced in manifest)

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have a special need for my app. I must force the app to work only in portrait mode, but i need to know when the user has moved the phone to landscape mode. Why? because i am displaying a opengl view with a texture image, and when the user changues the phone position to landscape mode i must rotate the polygon without reseting the activity. Then i must force portrait mode on manifest, because i dont want that my onCreate method gets called again.

Please, can someone tell me how to achieve this?

I know how to rotate the image, i only need to know when the user has moved the phone to landscape position, but with portrait forced on manifest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By "forced portrait", I assume you mean adding `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in the manifest. All you need to do to know when orientation has changed is to also add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` to the `<activity>` declaration in the manifest; and then override `onConfigurationChanged()` in your `Activity`.

Isn't this what you need? Doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

Read the following posts;
If you set it to sensor and then check in your activity what orientation the phone is in you can take actions accordingly.

Force orientation
[Force "portrait" orientation mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885620/force-portrait-orientation-mode)

Then read this, specially the first answer with android:screenOrientation="sensor"
[Force an Android activity to always use landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150287/force-an-android-activity-to-always-use-landscape-mode)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation