# Negate orientation change - Android

Tags: android, screen-orientation, orientation-changes, android-orientation, android-screen

I'm developing an app that only some pages can be displayed on landscape orientation, I do not want to lock the screen on display, I wish to deny Android do a orientation change.

There's something that I can use for it? Like, at runtime on orientation change, Android asks if it's possible to go to that orientation?

If there's not, how can I lock the current screen orientation? I know that setRequestedOrientation can do that, but it implies in discover the current orientation (and even discover the correct orientation like 'normal' or 'inverse' portraits/landscapes) and lock to it.

EDIT:
There's only ONE activity on this app, and based on it's state (that changes trough time and user input) it can be rotated or not, that is my problem.

As seen at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html about configuration changes:

"Handle the configuration change yourself
Prevent the system from restarting your activity during certain configuration changes, but receive a callback when the configurations do change, so that you can manually update your activity as necessary."

Even with that the configuration changes, I wish to block this behavior before that.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150287/force-an-android-activity-to-always-use-landscape-mode ?

Comment: Just to add to what @BrianNickel said, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2150558/1438733) is probably what you're looking for. You may also want to look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android).

Comment: My question is how to deny on runtime the device to not change the orientation

Comment: I tried some onConfigurationChanges approach not working, even if I consume the event the screen rotates and displays the old orientation rotated, but this also make my screen do not recreate the Views, and it's important too.

Comment: "Even with that the configuration changes, I wish to block this behavior before that" -- that is not possible, short of writing your own custom firmware. You cannot stop the configuration from changing. At most, you manage the *effects* of a configuration change.

Comment: Well, it's not possible, so I used the setRequestOrientation solution.

Answer (score 3):

Add one othese to each activity.

```
public void checkActivityPos() {

    if(somthing == "this") {
        myActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }else {
        myActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, there's only ONE activity, and based on it's state it can be rotated or not, that is my problem.

Comment: you can call this method in your activity at any time.

Comment: I agree with @Dr.Dredel  Maybe use conditional statements to check where the activity is... Seen my edit above.

Comment: Well, maybe this can be a approach, i'll give a try

Comment: I solved with this solution, but this is not the answer for the question I made (about deny the change instead of forcing one). Thanks!

Comment: Youre welcome.  I dont think there is a way to 'deny' the rotation change.