# How to start a foreign Activity/Application with a specific orientation?

Tags: android

Starting a foreigin Activity/Application is quite easy.

```
Intent intentHandle = this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.browser");

this.startActivity(intentHandle);
```

But is there any possibility to specify the orientation, the foreign Activity/Application is forced to use?

Comment: This is (probably) possible as I see apps like this one (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coinsoft.android.orientcontrol , I think this is what you want). I doubt there are any public APIs to do this at the SDK level, other possibilities would be to build your own android version or use reflection to access undocumented internal APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the source code of the application. To my knowledge, this is not possible. As Each application can handle orientation change differently or just not do it at all.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can specify the orientation for the activity in the manifest.

[Force an Android activity to always use landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150287/force-an-android-activity-to-always-use-landscape-mode)

Comment: It looks like he's attempting to start an activity that's not in his own package.