# Launching External Activity In Portrait

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest, android

I have implemented an application, in which runs in a 50 inch touch display. In my manifest I have declared that the application should run on Reverse Portrait mode. Now My application is using an external activity from another app(MapsWithMeLite). How can I make the external activity to run as reverse portrait as well? Do I have to do something in my manifest? Is there any way I can declare that external on my manifest and declare it to use Reverse Portrait?Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the behaviour of that second activity is controlled by the other app's manifest, not the one in your app. 
If the activity you are calling is capable of rotating (doesn't have a fixed orientation defined) then it should rotate to be correctly shown in the current orientation.

Comment: Hello Martin, and thank you for your reply, well, the other application is picking up my launch icon, so it must be connected to my app somehow,because parameters are passed over. So i guess if I knew the activity name, maybe i could do something with it. Iam not only launching an external Intent, but am also passing parameters to it, so there must be a way of controlling it!

Comment: The app that owns the activity you are launching from your app has dynamic orientation (it changes orientation when you rotate the device) or it always runs in a fixed orientation?
If it has a fixed orientation, I don't think you can override it.

Also, check this other question in Stackoverflow where one of the comments suggests an app to force a lock in the orientation.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833116/how-to-start-a-foreign-activity-application-with-a-specific-orientation

Comment: Hello Martin and thanks for your comment. Luckily the external Intent did not use a fixed orientation so declaring ReversePortrait on the master Manifest file , forced the other app to rotate!