# Is there a way to force different orientations for different devices?

Tags: android, device-orientation

I want my app to be always displayed landscape on tablets, but it should rotate ok on mobiles. Is there a way to do this (besides of having 2 different apks)?

Answer (score 1):

Use a method to [check whether the device is a tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android), then [force orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150287/force-an-android-activity-to-always-use-landscape-mode) if it's true.

```
// From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android
public boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 4);
    boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
    return (xlarge || large);
}

// ...

// Do this from any Activity you do not wish to rotate on tablets:
if (isTablet(this))
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: AFAIK there are devices in which these instructions don't work as expected, they keep on waiting for the views to be setup, etc

Comment: "Waiting for the views to be set up"? I'm not really sure what you mean. As long as you do this before `setContentView()`, it has no views to wait for.