# How to keep a Android app in landscape

Tags: performance, android, android-windowmanager

I want to know if there was good way to keep my application from rotating, but let it go switch from landscape to landscape reversed?

I've only found this:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

How can I restrict my applications to those two states?

Comment: You can do it from the manifest thanks to android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" since API 9 (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't wanna say it but `RTM` !

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen), in your `Manifest` add this to your activity you wanna let rotate :

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

Comment: sorry, I've missed that one, but i've read the doc about activity :/
Funny though the RTFM xD

Comment: @zlgdev  Please, do you think you could give me some advice/ideas over here http://goo.gl/E37NSu

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `<activity>` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

Or if you want to do it programmatically you can add this to your activity

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look here (duplicate)

[Force an Android activity to always use landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150287/force-an-android-activity-to-always-use-landscape-mode)

You have to define this in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do one thing, just put `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in every `<activity>` tag of your `manifest` file

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line to activities added in Manifests

```
<activity android:name=".youractivityName" android:screenOrientation="portrait"  />
```